# Generate new values in dataframe based on other data

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate an additional column in a results dataframe based on a filter operation from another dataframe that does not match in size.

So, I have my source dataframe source_df:

```py
| id  | date                  |
| ----------------------------- 
| 1   | 2100-01-01            |
| 2   | 2021-12-12            |
| 3   | 2018-09-01            |
| 4   | 2100-01-01            |
```

and the target dataframe target_df. Both dataframe lengths and amount of ids do not necessarily match:

```py
| id   | 
| -------- 
| 1    | 
| 2    | 
| 3    | 
| 4    | 
| 5.   |
...
| 100  |
```

I actually want to find out which dates lie more than 30 days in the past.

To do so, I created a query

```
query = (pd.datetime.today() - pd.to_datetime(source_df["date"], errors="coerce")).dt.days > 30
ids = source_df[query]["id"]

--> ids = [2,3]
```

My intention is to calculate a column "date_in_past"
that contains the values 0 and 1. If the date difference is greater than 30 days, a 1 is inserted, 0 elsewise.

The target_df should look like:

```py
| id | date_in_past  |
| -----------------  | 
| 1   | 0            |
| 2   | 1            |
| 3   | 1            |
| 4   | 0            |
| 5   | 0            |
```

Both indices and df lengths do not match.
I tried to create a lambda function

```
map_query = lambda x: 1 if x in ids.values else 0
```

When I try to pass the target frame `map_query(target_df["id"])` a ValueError is thrown, that "lengths must match to compare".

How can I assign the new column "date_in_past" having the calculated values based on the source dataframe?

Comment: What do you mean by the statement "date difference is greater than 30 "?  What two dates are used to compute difference?  Which dataframe is used in this computation? Which dataframe do you want the added column to be attached to?

Comment: I am computing the day difference in the variable `query`. The difference is calculated between today and `source_df["date"]`. If the day difference is greater than 30, I want to store in `target_df["date_in_the_past"]` either a 1 if the criteria is fullfilled, or 0 otherwise.